# Retrieving nested data from multiple records in a Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve nested data from multiple records and display them in a ListView. My data is recorded like so:

[image: The first ID is a groupID and the second is the groupVaccinationID]

I want to display the GroupNumber and the GroupVaccinationDate of all GroupVaccinations recorded in a listView but at the moment the listView remains empty when I run the following code:

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listItemAllGroupVaccinations);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("groupVaccinations");
        groupVaccinations = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot groupVaccinationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    GroupVaccination groupVaccination = groupVaccinationSnapshot.getValue(GroupVaccination.class);
                    groupVaccinations.add(groupVaccination);
                }
                AllGroupVaccinationList groupVaccinationInfoAdapter = new AllGroupVaccinationList(ActivityAllGroupVaccinations.this, groupVaccinations);
                listView.setAdapter(groupVaccinationInfoAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaston's answer will show you all vaccinations in a single group. If instead you want to show all vaccinations in all groups, you can loop over the nested snapshots in your `onDataChange`:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("groupVaccinations");
groupVaccinations = new ArrayList<>();
AllGroupVaccinationList groupVaccinationInfoAdapter = new AllGroupVaccinationList(ActivityAllGroupVaccinations.this, groupVaccinations);
listView.setAdapter(groupVaccinationInfoAdapter);

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot groupVaccinationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            for(DataSnapshot vaccinationSnapshot : groupVaccinationSnapshot.getChildren()){
                GroupVaccination groupVaccination = vaccinationSnapshot.getValue(GroupVaccination.class);
                groupVaccinations.add(groupVaccination);
            }
        }
        groupVaccinationInfoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

I also changed the code to call `groupVaccinationInfoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, so that you can keep using the same adapter and update it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go one level deeper where your id `-LZk5tpB5PXqHVJkj8Vz` (GroupID) contains all the sub pushKeys (groupVaccinationID) with data inside.

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listItemAllGroupVaccinations);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("groupVaccinations").child("-LZk5tpB5PXqHVJkj8Vz");
        groupVaccinations = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot groupVaccinationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    GroupVaccination groupVaccination = groupVaccinationSnapshot.getValue(GroupVaccination.class);
                    groupVaccinations.add(groupVaccination);
                }
                AllGroupVaccinationList groupVaccinationInfoAdapter = new AllGroupVaccinationList(ActivityAllGroupVaccinations.this, groupVaccinations);
                listView.setAdapter(groupVaccinationInfoAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

### EDIT

The `-LZk5tpB5PXqHVJkj8Vz` child should be avoided since is hardcoded to show you this example, instead, you should take that child key from where you get your **GroupID**, doing that you can get as Frank says all the vaccinations from each **GroupID**.